# Find max value(s) of certain key

Tags: python, dictionary, max

I need the max value of 'cost' and if there are two or more occurrences of the same key with same value (max) then I need all of them into a single list.

**For Example:**

```
fruits = [{'nama':'oranges','id':9635,'cost':23}, {'nama':'lemons','id':946,'cost':17}, {'nama':'apples','id':954,'cost':16}, {'nama':'oranges','id':989,'cost':23}]
```

**I need output to be like:**

```
result = [{'nama':'oranges','id':9635,'cost':23}, {'nama':'oranges','id':989,'cost':23}]
```

How do we do this?

Comment: Tried @jpp answer and it worked perfectly for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Calculate the max cost, then use a list comprehension:

```
from operator import itemgetter

max_cost = max(map(itemgetter('cost'), fruits))
# or max_cost = max(i['cost'] for i in fruits)

res = [i for i in fruits if i['cost'] == max_cost]

print(res)

[{'nama': 'oranges', 'id': 9635, 'cost': 23},
 {'nama': 'oranges', 'id': 989, 'cost': 23}]
```

Comment: I was thinking of just doing something like `max(fruits, key=lambda x: x['cost'])`, but that only returns the first max item. Is there a workaround?

Answer (score 2):

```
fruits = [{'nama':'oranges','id':9635,'cost':23}, {'nama':'lemons','id':946,'cost':17}, {'nama':'apples','id':954,'cost':16}, {'nama':'oranges','id':989,'cost':23}]

costs = []
for i in fruits:
    costs.append(i['cost'])
max_val = max(costs)

result = []
for i in fruits:
    if i['cost'] == max_val:
        result.append(i)

print(result)
```

First, go through the  list of dictionaries and grab all the costs and append them to a list. Next, find the max value in the list. Then, go through the dictionary list again, and append each dictionary with a cost equal to the max val to the result list. Then print the result list.